# css uikit grid component: text overlapping in div in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, uikit, getuikit

I am working on the following web page using the uikit grid component to display books/journal subscriptions:
http://booktest.ersnet.org/PublicationsSubscriptions/

Everything looks fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer. But with Google Chrome I have an issue with the display of the descriptions of the items. Description texts are overlapping into the other columns.

I already searched on the web and tried solving the problem by using some css tricks as: display:block; overflow:hidden; clear:both; 
With no success at the moment.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your text in a div and put a width of 90%

```
<div style="width:90%">
     <p>
     your text is here
     </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set the word-wrap attribute to break-word.

Example:

```
*{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```